# HyperSwitch alt+tab broken?

Tags: macos, applications, application-switcher

[HyperSwitch](http://bahoom.com/hyperswitch) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour stopped working 2-3 days ago. It simply does nothing.
I haven't changed my HyperSwitch's preferences and I don't remember installing or updating anything that would create a conflict.
However cmd+tab window preview is working, so the app is clearly up and running.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem? Or everything works well?
I have already contacted the creator of the app to get some support.

Meanwhile, is there any free app with the same <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> window scrolling feature?

Comment: I see the same behaviour, do you got any feedback from the developer?

Comment: I have no answer yet

Answer (score 10):

After months of digging I found out what was my problem. As I visited this page like a million times I'll leave here my story as it may be helpful

My issue was related to the new "Secure Input" feature of os x. When Secure Input is enabled, apps like HyperSwitch, Contexts etc... will not be able to grap hotkeys.

Some app may be bugged and not release the secure input lock, or (like in my case) you may have some issue with Iterm2. In this case just [disable it](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html#documentation-menu-items.html), Iterm2 menu -> Secure Keyboard Entry and you have your life back!

Comment: And if for some reason you can't toggle it in the menu, try disabling System Integrity Protection. Worked for me at least (MacOS Mojave) https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html

Comment: I had to reboot to make the *Secure Keyboard Entry* be unchecked.

Answer (score 8):

I found the real answer to this question in reading [this](https://smilesoftware.com/textexpander/secureinput) and [this](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/disable-secure-input/2410/3). What happens is your mac gets stuck in "SecureInput" mode. When this happens, HyperSwitch won't work, and I also noticed keyboard events won't be picked up by Karabiner-EventViewer. If you use iTerm2, you may notice that in the `iTerm2 -> Secure Keyboard Entry` is stuck on, and you can't toggle it. This has nothing to do with iTerm2; some other process is hanging on to SecureInput and iTerm2 is simply reflecting that state.

Find the offending process. Run

```
ioreg -l -w 0 | grep SecureInput
```

and hunt for a PID. In my case, I found `"kCGSSessionSecureInputPID"=102` so I killed it with `sudo kill 102`. 102 was `loginwindow` so this logged me out, but I was able to log back in and most of my processes could be resumed. However, maybe some other app is hanging onto "SecureInput" so killing it won't be as drastic. After, HyperSwitch worked again, and keyboard events were also showing in Karabiner-EventViewer.

Comment: Terminal and iterm2 have this "Secure Keyboard Entry" setup. To see the list of processes use the above command then turn it off in the settings

Comment: This worked for me. It kind of killed everything running and logged me out. Then when I logged back in, Hyperswitch was working fine.

Comment: I used your command and found a PID. Then ran `sudo kill <pid>` and boom, all my Chrome windows closed. I had a weird experience with Bitwarden's login screen (web based) just before so I'm thinking Bitwarden/Chrome locked the secure input... Just reporting here because this was the best answer explaining what is happening that I found so far

Answer (score 3):

I thought HyperSwitch had broken until I realised that I was using the wrong buttons to switch between apps. HyperSwitch defaults to using `Option` + `Tab`, but I was using `Command` + `Tab.

After changing the command options in the preference menu and restarting HyperSwitch everything started working for me. This following image may provide clarification.

[image: HyperSwitch Preferences Menu]

Answer (score 1):

No idea what feature you are looking for as I've never used HyperSwitch and their website doesn't show much.

For a "better than Apple's" Application Switcher, I use [LiteSwitch X](http://sysbeep.com/).
If you want one that switches between windows instead of full Applications, try [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/)

Comment: what is LiteSwitch X really? Witch is paid, I asked for free options... @Insomniac

Comment: LiteSwitch is very similar to the built-in app switcher but a bit customizable.  Change the window color, show background apps, quit an app, etc.  Only windowing options are to show all windows or just the front-most window when switching.  If you want a switcher that shows the windows and lets you pick a specific window, you would have to try Witch or get HyperSwitch working again.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who comes here for the same question but still not yet solves it.

I encountered the same question and just solved it not by all of the ways listed above.

Here are the procedures of how I solve it:

1. uninstall the HyperSwith app.
2. use the cmd `sudo find /Users -name "*HyperSwitch*"` to find out all of the cache files and configuration files of HyperSwith and then, remove them all by the cmd `rm -rf files`.
3. restart your computer.
4. reinstall HyperSwith.

Answer (score 0):

lock your mac, then unlock, you'll found that it works

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer from Enrico Carlesso I managed to figure out a way to fix this issue without signing out.

In my case it was iTerm2 that created the problem, and you can solve it without restarting iTerm2.

Fix:

- Select the `iTerm` menu item, select `Secure Keyboard Entry` so that it is selected (checked)
- Write `sudo ls` in a terminal window. Write your password and press enter.
- Select the `iTerm` menu item again, make sure `Secure Keyboard Entry` is deselected / unchecked.

Now Hyperswitch worked for me again.